# Im getting an error when submitting a json to a rest endpoint

Tags: json

Please I need some help regarding an error with Json. I am doing a homework test an trying to upload json to a database .. below is the Json

```
"{\"operation\":\"create\",\"tableName\":\"api\",\"payload\":{\"Item\":{ '"id":"334'","name":"'Lukas'", "occupation":"'Mjor'"' }}}"
```

But when I try to upload it I get an error:

```
{
"errorType": "SyntaxError",
"errorMessage": "Unexpected token i in JSON at position 83",
"trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 83",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:67:14)"
]
```

}

Please can someone help I read a bunch of articles still havent had a clue

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to ident the same characters with .

```
"{\"operation\":\"create\",\"tableName\":\"apilambdadb\",\"payload\":{\"Item\":{\"id\":\"334\",\"name\":\"Mihael\", \"occupation\":\"Mjo\"}}}"
```